# Best way to get max Id from multiple FK

Tags: entity-framework-6.1

ALBUM have songs and each song contains History. The History is auto-encrement. Multiple songs have a history but I want just one max Id value.

I treid this

```
item.LastHitId = item.sound_track.Select(s => s.SoundHistory.LastOrDefault().Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

But just take last value from first song. Need last value from any song.

Answer (score 0):

```
long lastHitId = item.sound_track.Select(item2 => item2.SoundHistory.Max(m => m.Id)).Concat(new long[] { 0 }).Max();
```